# How to stretch this vector by increasing its size using interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have many vectors with different sizes and with many values each. How do I increase the size of the vectors? Should I use interpolation? Here is an example of one of the vectors:

```
a = np.array(data['col1'])
a
    array([
    ....
    ....
    1.58795599271e-18,
    1.44291516626e-17,
    9.38543028522e-18,
    1.26688244651e-17,
    2.92337581236e-18,
    3.94537400278e-18,
    3.5377910957e-18,
    2.28690272401e-18
    ....
    .... ])
```

The size of the array is 2244.

How do I change the size to 3153?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) performs 1D linear interpolation:

```
import numpy as np

# suppose this is your given array
size = 2244
data = np.random.random(size)

xloc = np.arange(size)
newsize = 3153
new_xloc = np.linspace(0, size, newsize)
new_data = np.interp(new_xloc, xloc, data)
```

You could use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for nearest, quadratic, cubic or higher order spline interpolation.

If your "many vectors" are in a Pandas DataFrame, you may be looking for [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), but there the interpolation is done relative to a fixed DataFrame index (which plays the role of `new_xloc` above). Its usefulness to you may depend on how your vectors of various sizes is laid out in the DataFrame and what your desired result is.